# Variable width textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox

I am wondering is this possible to do in JS:
I want to make some text box with some width. But I want to add controls so user can simply change its width and position.
I'm hoping to automatize diploma printing in my school, and I need tool for fast and simple adjustment during form filling.

Comment: What have you done? Show code.

Comment: use textarea , most of the browsers allow you to resize it

Comment: I have no code to show yet. I am still learning JS and this project is in future. I think textarea will not do because I think it could be changed only down and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [interact.js](http://interactjs.io) and its examples.

Remember that you can natively resize `<textarea>` elements with this:

[image]

Combine it and interact.js's dragging feature and you are done.

Here's a snippet: lines marked with `// *` were added by me, otherwise this example is exactly from the interact.js website.

I added those lines so we do not drag the element if the mouse is inside the "resizer rectangle"

```js
// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },
    // enable autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,

    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    // call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                     event.dy * event.dy)|0) + 'px');
    }
  });

  function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var rel_x = event.clientX - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left; // *
    var rel_y = event.clientY - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top;  // *
    var w     = event.target.offsetWidth;                                  // *
    var h     = event.target.offsetHeight;                                 // *
    var threshold = 20;                                                    // *
    if(rel_x > w - 20 && rel_y > h - 20) return;                           // *
    
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  // this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
  window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
```

```css
#drag-1, #drag-2 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 6.5em;
  margin: 10%;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: black;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

#drag-me::before {
  content: "#" attr(id);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.interactjs.io/v1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="drag-1" class="draggable">
  <p> You can drag one element </p>
</textarea>
<textarea id="drag-2" class="draggable">
    <p> with each pointer </p>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Weary Adventurer! This is it!

Comment: @Zoran make sure to upvote this answer and accept it if it solved your problem.